# Calling .recv(1024) and .send() twice, nothing happening (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, process, send, recv

I am trying to learn Socket coding right now, and I wrote a little piece of Process-to-Process communication.
This is the Servercode:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 17752
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
    (client, address) = s.accept()
    print(address, 'just connected!')
    message = input("Would you like to close the connection? (y/n)")
    if message == 'y':
        message = "False"
        client.send(message.encode(encoding="utf_8"))
        client.close()
        break
    elif message == 'n':
        print("sending message...")
        testing = "Do you want to close the connection?"
        client.send(testing.encode(encoding='utf_8'))
        print("sent!")
```

And the Clientcode:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 17752

client.connect((host, port))

while True:
    print("awaiting closing message...")
    closing = client.recv(1024)
    closing = closing.decode(encoding='utf_8')
    print("Closing message recieved and decoded")
    if closing == 'False':
        print("message is false, breaking loop")
        break
    else:
        print("Awaiting message...")
        recieved = client.recv(1024)
        recieved = recieved.decode(encoding='utf_8')
        print("Message recieved and decoded")
        print(recieved)
        sd = input('(y/n) >')
        if sd == 'y':
            print("Closing connection")
            client.close()
            break

print("Sorry, the server closed the connection!")
```

What it is meant to do?

It is basically to learn and practice socket coding.
It should be a program that sends data from the Server to the Client with both being able to terminate the connection by answering y or n to the questions.
If both sides keep answering n the program just keeps running.
As soon as someone answers y it terminates either the Server or the client.

Now, I don't know what to heck is wrong there.
If I type 'y' for the Servers question "Would you like to close this connection?" it all works as it should.

If I type 'n' the Server does what it should, but the client does not recieve anything. Most of the 'print' statements are for debugging. Thats how I know the Server works fine.

What is wrong there? I tried to find it, I couldn't.

I am kinda new to python and new to socket coding. So keep it easy please.
Thanks.

(I run it with Batch scripts under Win10 cmd)
(Since it is Process-to-Process it is probably not called a "Server"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code each `connect` should have a matching `accept` on server side.
Your client `connect`s once per session,
but the server `accept`s after each message, so  at the point where the second `recv` is invoked the server is already trying to accept another client.
Apparently your  server is supposed to handle only one client, 
so you can just move the call to `accept` out of the loop:

```
s.listen(5)
(client, address) = s.accept()
print(address, 'just connected!')

while True:
    message = raw_input("Would you like to close the connection? (y/n)")
```